# What is the extra random port in kafka and how to set it to bind to localhost

Tags: apache-kafka, port

This happens on host and docker images, besides the famous 9092 port, there is another dynamic port that kafka listens to.

I am using the /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh to run kafka.

```
ps -ef |grep kafka |grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'
15580

netstat -tnpl |grep 15580

tcp6 0 0 :::37023 ::: LISTEN 15580/java*
tcp6 0 0 192.168.64.18:9092 :::* LISTEN 15580/java
```

What is the port "37023" above? how to disable it? Can it be bind to "localhost" ?

Comment: Have you managed to find out how to disable that bugger?

Answer (score 1):

It is Kafka JMX port. You can solve it by modifying `kafka_2.13-3.6.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh` and adding this new lines before last line `exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS kafka.Kafka "$@"`:

```
export JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9000}
export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual Kafka process only listens on the 9092 port by default.

Can you run `lsof -i :37023`, or whatever other dynamic port you get?  That would get the PID of the process that is listening on that TCP port, and will probably point to the culprit.

Comment: It is the kafka process, `lsof -i :42888
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    28799 root  112u  IPv6 114965      0t0  TCP *:42888 (LISTEN)`